# To control 3D type Snake Game's movement when turning by WebGL

Tags: three.js, game-physics, babylonjs

I hope to create a 3D type Snake game by Babylon or THREE.js.

Here's the picture about how i want the snake to move when the snake to turn left or turn right.
[movement comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S29w9.png)

That is, I want the snake to move more "smoothly", just like the car's movement when it turn left or turn right.

Do I need skeleton animation to achieve this goal? If so, could you give me a solution/suggestion about how to implement it.

Comment: Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I would recommend starting with how the movement should work. I think there are some simple algorithms for how to achieve this. I would recommend checking out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbgDqyy8bIw. This should give you an idea for how the control should work. Then how to implement it in threejs is up to you. Going the bones path may be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential (likely simpler) way to do it would be to use a particle system. When snake grows you could just change the params on the particle system, then the engine would be responsible for handling smoothing.

Particle system would just need to adhere to the following rules:

1. Particles shoot out in one direction from the head mesh.
2. Particles minimum_lifetime = maximum_lifetime
3. Particle minimum_speed = maximum_speed

Then as it grows in size you just increment the particles direction. And you then just compare head position to it's particle (tail) positions to check for collisions.

The default particle system in BJS doesn't as far as I know support collisions officially, but you could query the positions of the particles to check for collisions, or use the solid particle system which allows for physics. (SPS is probably the best way to go in the end).

Here is an example playground however just to demonstrate the movement.

https://playground.babylonjs.com/#PLRKFW#1